# Python Search and Scrape

Tags: python, search, scrape

I have a problem I'd like to know if it's worth spending the time trying to solve with Python. I have a large CSV file of scientific names of fishes. I would like to cross-reference that CSV file with a large database of fish morphology information (www.fishbase.ca) and have the code return the maximum length of each fish. Basically, I need to create code that will search the fishbase website for each fish, then find the maximum length info on the page and return it to me in a CSV file. The last two parts are relatively straightforward, but the first part is where I'm stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is really a data analysis question and it's tough to say anything without seeing the data. One key question will be how predictably your scientific names will match in both data sets. Matching on free text fields is often quite cumbersome if both sets weren't created under the same requirements / standards. I might start by picking a dozen or so names at random out of your set and searching the fishbase set to see how many matches you get.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My CSV file looks pretty clean and is returning good matches from the fishbase.ca site.

Comment: Awesome. This might also be a good task for a SQLite database. __Update__: didn't realize you don't have direct access to the fishbase dataset. Per @gewh, that's the next thing you need to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can generate the url directly from the genus and species, ie

rainbow trout (oncorhynchus mykiss) becomes

```
http://www.fishbase.ca/summary/Oncorhynchus-mykiss.html
```

so something like

```
def make_url(genus, species):
    return (
        "http://www.fishbase.ca/summary/{}-{}.html"
        .format(genus.title(), species.lower())
    )
```

Looking at the page source, the html is severely unsemantic; while parsing html with regular expressions is evil and awful, I really think it's the easiest method in this case:

```
import re

fishlength = re.compile("max length : ([\d.]+) ([cm]{1,2})", re.I).search

def get_length_in_cm(html):
    m = fishlength(html)
    if m:     # match found
        value = float(m.group(1))
        unit  = m.group(2)
        if unit == "cm":
            return value
        elif unit == "m":
            return value * 100.
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown unit: {}".format(unit))
    else:
        raise ValueError("Length not found")
```

then grabbing each page,

```
import csv
import requests
from time import sleep

DELAY = 2
GENUS_COL = 4
SPECIES_COL = 5

with open("fish.csv") as inf:
    next(inf)  # skip header row
    for row in csv.reader(inf):
        url  = make_url(row[GENUS_COL], row[SPECIES_COL])

        # should add error handling, in case
        #   that page doesn't exist
        html = requests.get(url).text

        length = get_length_in_cm(html)

        # now store the length value somewhere

        # be nice, don't pound their site
        sleep(DELAY)
```

Comment: I've been away from this depth of coding for over a year, so I'm going to need to bring myself back up to speed, but it looks like this may work for my needs, and I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to use the information in other web applications you will need to use an API to get hold of their data.

Fishbase.ca (or .org) does not have an official public-facing API. There is some [chat in 2013](https://github.com/ropensci/rfishbase/tree/rfishbase2.0) about creating a RESTful API which would be just the ticket for what you need, but this hasn't happened yet (don't hold your breath).

An alternative is using the name of the fish you need to lookup, dropping that into the URI (eg www.fishbase.ca/fish/Rainbow+Trout) and then using Xquery or similar to drill down the DOM to find the maximum length.

Unfortunately, fishbase does not have the sort of URIs needed for this method either, [this](http://fishbase.ca/summary/239) is the URI for Rainbow Trout - uses an ID rather than a name to easily look up.

I would suggest looking into another data provider looking for either of these two APIs.

Regarding the second method: the site owners may not appreicate you using their website in this manner. Ask them beforehand if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I need to use the fishbase data for purposes of consistency for the project. When you say "the second method," to what are you referring?

Comment: The URI method I explained, although it looks like Hugh found a way to make it work.